# ExpressionEngine: Upload Files form fields displaying on add/edit form when they shouldn’t

Tags: jquery, forms, expressionengine

The Choose an upload directory dropdown menu and Choose File button are appearing below the footer at the bottom of my add/edit forms, even on forms that don’t have file uploads. In the developer console I see this error message:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #
```

I don’t think that message is correct: I replaced the jQuery script with one from the Google CDN, and I don’t see that message if I add or edit channel form fields, which points to the same jQuery file.

I’m on ExpressionEngine 2.5.2 and just updated ExpressionEngine, Channel Images, Low Reorder, Matrix, MX Google Map, and Wygwam to the latest versions. I've also deleted the contents of my themes/third_party folders and replaced them from fresh downloads.

The jQuery error message is appearing on most, but not all, of my add/edit forms that use Matrix and/or Wygwam. I have a form that uses Channel Images, Matrix, and Wygwam that doesn’t show the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had a "weird" jQuery problem last week.  I finally traced it to the fact that SafeCracker was loading its own jQuery after the one in my template.  The solution-that-worked was to put `include_jquery="no"` in my `{exp:safecracker}` tag.  It might be worth a try here if you're bringing in your own jQuery, but I don't really know versions of jQuery are fine for SafeCracker.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It wasn't the problem I was having, but it'll be something to try if I have a similar problem later.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by deleting my entire themes folder, uploading fresh copies of the EE and third-party themes, and clearing my browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that this may be due to extra third party theme folders, or by incorrectly installing EE-Garage.com's (excellent) Override.css.

Make sure to follow their instructions correctly in installing Override.css and NSM Morphine theme.

If the field still behaves oddly, simply try uninstalling Override.css from the control panel.